# Is there any way to publicly request 'Page Views' of any website URL from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am not sure if this is possible, nor that I could find any leads yet.

I want to be able to return only the `total 'Page Views' number` of any website URL, that uses Google Analytics. With GA API, I can use this by logging-in but only for the limited websites I am authorized to see the stats.

However, I only need to display **total page views for requested page URL** (not entire domain & no information is stored on the server.

Is there any way we can achieve this?

**EDIT:** 
After answers from Tom & Blexy -- I would like to rephrase it.

What're the best ways to estimate page views of any URL `example.com/this-is-url`, from single/multiple sources, like Alexa?

TIA :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking if there's any way to see GA data for other sites - say, stackoverflow.com. If so, then no, there is no way to access GA reporting for sites your Google account does not have access to.

Comment: Thanks @tom -- I knew it, but thought if there is any way! Thanks for confirmation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Google Analytics superProxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy). It will require some setup, but I believe it's one of the only ways to publish your data publicly without the use of a dashboard, etc.

Comment: Hey @blexy, thanks a ton. This is interesting however, I won't be having a chance to tell people to enable sharing. 

The page clearly says `... allows you to publicly share your Google Analytics reporting data...` & I won't have chance to tell people to do it nor there is any reward for doing so (as yet) .